# how can i use a domain to point to my server?

Tags: domain-server

Lets say I have a new domain I just purchased:

Www.server.domain.com

And I want that to access my server from anywhere.

At home, my ip is static, 192.168.2.47, but I dont really know where to go from there.

Im using Ubuntu 13.10 as my server machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general DOMAIN NAME  question not specific for Ubuntu.

You need to login to your registrar account and create an A record for server.domain.com pointing to your home static public IP address provided by your ISP/Telco. The 192.168.2.47 is a private ip address therefore you can't point your domain name A record into it.

Answer (score -1):

First. Go to Google and search whats my ip. It will show u what the ip to your router is.

Second. Go to where ever u bought your domain from and Pont it to the ip you got for your router.

Third. Go into your router and into port forwarding(depends on router on what it is called). And forward to the ip of your servers local ip. And for the port use 80 on start and end port.

Then when u type in your domain name( www.metrikcorp.com is mine that runs on my servers in my house.)it should take you to your server.

P.S. depending on your internet provider and what kinda package you have with them. most internet providers block port 80 unless you have  business grade internet.
You will also need a http server(I use apache2) on that machine. 
Hope this helps